# (int*) Malloc memory and use of askaris

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I saw on some online sources that they allocate a block of memory for an array of n integers as follows:

```
memory = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int))
```

What's the role of `(int*)` here?

Comment: Nothing, it's a mistake that appeared in a popular 1970s book and people have been copying it ever since without thinking about it.  `memory = malloc(n * sizeof(int));` or `memory = malloc(n * sizeof *memory);` is correct. The latter has the advantage that you cannot accidentally name the wrong type and thereby allocate the wrong amount of memory.